# Why do I need to call Firebase's OnDataChange method to get a Datasnapshot?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

It seems restricting that I can only get a snapshot from my database to read data from on data change. Is there something I'm missing about OnDataChange?

What if I want to populate a page with data read dynamically from my database, yet no data is changing in the database? I still need to call OnDataChange?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_once

Answer (score 2):

Firebase's `onDataChange` fires immediately with a snapshot of the current value in the database and subsequently whenever the data changes.

In fact, the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events) says this:

> This method is triggered once when the listener is attached and again every time the data, including children, changes.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is you can't block the User Interface with a long running task such as a database query or network request. At best the user will have an unresponsive application at worst an "application not responding exception" (ANR)crash will happen. That's why it is designed with a listener pattern. I assume this is android we are talking about, however the answer is valid for other platforms. If you are doing this on a background thread yes you could do what you are saying, in theory. I don't think firebase is designed that way.